# Detecting standalone mode in iPhone

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am trying to detect if my jquerymobile app is running as an APP (i.e from home screen). My current code is:

```
if (window.navigator.standalone)
  Data.isRunningAsApp = true;
```

Problem is I've heard this code is better according to [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm)

```
if (("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone) {}
```

I get what the first segment is doing (testing is the property exists) but I don't understand the second segment. (From a syntax perspective I thought I did, but it seems contradictory to me!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the paragraph above the code example in the blog post. The `if` *is* detecting for **a supported browser that is *not* in the app mode**.

Comment: Also, if you read through the comments, you will find out your approach is fine!

Answer (score 1):

It's just:

1. first checking if the object window.navigator has a property called "standalone"
2. then comparing the property window.navigator.standalone to FALSE ->  !window.navigator.standalone is the same as window.navigator.standalone != true